# Codeigniter writes/creates folder under user Apache

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am required to add files/ create directories and do all sorts of file based operation with regards to the host system (Linux Based). Currently I am able to perform all of the above file operations. But currently user "apache" is the owner and writer to all these files. I would like to change this to a username of my choice.

Thanks For your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via group, add all the users you want to the group and give thge group permission to manipulate the folder,
You can do as follows:

1. Create a group:

`groupadd <groupname>`.

2. Assign users to that group:

`usermod -a -G <groupname>`

`-a` means append

`-G` group or groups you want to add the users to.

3. Give group the permission to write to the directory you want:

`chgrp -R <groupname> some_dir/`

Now, you can add users to the group above and then they all will have the same permission on folders.